# How do I dynamically append a large block of HTML to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I'm trying to learn web development, so I don't have much experience with the various languages and markups yet. I'm making a website with a blog that reads JSON data from the Tumblr v2 API. After getting the JSON data from Tumblr I want to add some of the data from each post to my own website's blog, here's the code that I've been trying to use..

```
<script>
function loadBlogPosts(){
$.getJSON("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/[MY_BLOG]/info?api_key=[MY_KEY]",
    function(blogData){
        $.each(blogData.posts, function(){
             $(#main_content).append( [BUNCH OF NESTED HTML] );
        });
    }
);
}
</script>
```

Before writing this, I thought it would be a good idea to make a 'layout' of each blog post in divs. So i came up with this:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post_header">
        <div class="post_title"></div>
        <div class="post_author"></div>
        <div class="post_date"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_content"></div>
    <div class="post_footer"></div>
</div>
```

But that's where I'm stuck. I know what I want to do, but I don't have enough experience with JavaScript/JQuery/JSON/HTML to know how to do it. I want parse the JSON blog data and, for each post, take the post content and apply it to that div structure while writing/appending it to the "main_content" div.. I tried copy-pasting that group of divs into the append function surrounded by quotes, but it became a real mess of quotes and slashes, and it didn't look like it was working correctly..

So, whats the best way for me to do that? Is there a good way of applying a big chunk of nested HTML elements while populating them with content from my JSON data? If not, what should I do? I'm still very new to HTML, JavaScript, and web coding in general, so I may be going about this completely wrong!

Comment: You should look into [client-side templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_templating).

Comment: I agree with @FrédéricHamidi: While you can do this in jQuery, your use case seems like client side templating would be a better fit because you're bringing raw data from the server (not rendered HTML) and putting it into some kind of template. Take a look at [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) or [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) for simple client-side templating (there are countless other options, of course).

Comment: Interesting, I'll continue to look into it! Thanks Frederic and Avish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want HIGH PERFORMANCE:**

In pure javascript the highest performing method is probably using `createDocumentFragment()`

```
function postEl(json){ // create a function for the POST element
 var post=document.createElement('div');
 post.className='post';
 var postHeader=document.createElement('div');
 postHeader.className='post_header';
 var postTitle=document.createElement('div');
 postTitle.className='post_title';
 postTitle.tectContent=json.title;
 //more code
 postHeader.appendChild(postTitle);
 //more code
 post.appendChild(postHeader);
 return post;
}

function appendPosts(){ // append each post to a fragment. and then to the main
 var frag=document.createDocumentFragment();
 for(/*each post*/){
  frag.appendChild(postEl(/*jsonPost*/));
 }
 document.getElementById('main_content').appendChild(frag);
}
```

**Precreating the structure should also increase the performance.**

```
cloneNode
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment

cloning the node also increases the performance by setting the valuse directly without recreating each individual node.

```
function appendPosts(js){
 var node=document.createElemtnt('div'),
 frag=document.createDocumentFragment();
 node.innerHTML='<div class="post_header"><div class="post_title"></div><div class="post_author"></div><div class="post_date"></div></div><div class="post_content"></div><div class="post_footer"></div>';
 for(var a=0,b;b=js.posts[a];++a){
  var newNode=node.cloneNode(true),
  childs=newNode.childNodes,
  header=childs[0].childNodes;
  header[0].textContent=b.title/*title from Postdata*/;
  header[1].textContent=b.author/*author from Postdata*/;
  header[2].textContent=b.date/*date from Postdata*/;
  childs[1].textContent=b.content/*content from Postdata*/;
  childs[2].textContent=b.footer/*footer from Postdata*/;
  frag.appendChild(newNode);
 }
 document.getElementById('main_content').appendChild(frag);
}

function loadBlogPosts(){
 $.getJSON("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/[MY_BLOG]/info?api_key=[MY_KEY]",
 appendPosts
)
```

This function should work now .. but as i don't exactly know the json response you may need to change the various post keys.

note: i put the fragment thing in a function so you have an idea how it works.
you should put the postEl content inside the appendPosts function... (thats also faster)

if you have any questions just ask.

**EDIT**

no they are not globals

```
var a,b,c,d; // not globals == var a;var b;var c;var d;
var a,b;c;d; // c d = gobal
// , comma affter a var allows you to not write 1000 times var.
```

**EDIT2**

```
 //.......
  frag.appendChild(newNode);
 }
 var topNode=document.createElement('div');
 topNode.className='post';
 topNode.appendChild(frag);
 document.getElementById('main_content').appendChild(topNode);
 //.....
```

Comment: Thanks for the extremely informative and detailed answer, cocco! I've learned a lot of new bits and pieces from this already! Quick question, why don't 'frag', 'childs', and 'header' have the 'var' keyword. This makes them globals right? Fragments, cloning, and node navigation are all new to me, so I'll read into it more and try to get it working! Thanks! :]

Comment: no they are not globals. comma allows you to not write var multiple times.

Comment: So it looks that the div that I had wrapping everything with class="post" is not there anymore. If i understand correctly, it's been replaced with the div that we used to create the node. Is there any way for me to set that top node/div to class="post"?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble with the for loop inside 'appendPosts'.. For some reason the first part of that function will run (I used a few console.logs to check), but everything after the for loop doesn't run. If I put a console.log before, inside, and after the loop, only the first one gets logged.. If I comment out the entire loop, the entire function runs, but If I comment out only the contents of the loop, the problem returns.. I'm a little bit confused by the format of that loop, coming from the C++ background. Any idea what might be going on? :\

Answer (score 2):

when you want to do everything with jquery yoiu could use something like this:

```
var post = $('<div class="post"></div>');
var postheader = $('<div class="post_header"></div>');

postheader.append('<div class="post_title"></div>');
postheader.append('<div class="post_author"></div>');

post.append(postheader);
post.append('<div class="post_content"></div>');
post.find('.post_title').text('my title');
post.find('.post_content').text('my content');

$('#main_content').append(post);
```

instead of `.text('my title')` you can use `.text(variable)` of course

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

```
$.each(blogData.posts, function(i,v){
    var cnt= '<div class="post">' +
             '<div class="post_header">' +
                     '<div class="post_title">'+ blogData.posts[i].title +'</div>' +
                     '<div class="post_author">'+ blogData.posts[i].author +'</div>' +
                     '<div class="post_date">'+ blogData.posts[i].date +'</div>' +
             '</div>' +
             '<div class="post_content">' +
                 blogData.posts[i].body +
             '</div>' +
             '<div class="post_footer">' +
             '</div>' +
         '</div>';
    $('#main_content').append(cnt);
});
```

Note that you don't need to split up all the lines, i've just done that to make it more readable. (I'm also not sure if all the variables are correct, (i don't think author exists) but it's just as a demo)

Comment: This is very simple and seems to work well! Thanks for the input Kristof!

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in a separate page, then append a whole html page into a div by using:

```
$('#containerDiv').load('page.htm');
```

Also, this is a good way to fragment the content.